React-ApexChart don't render donut chart
I am trying to render React-ApexChart using Functional Component.
I am following this demo on ApexChart https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/pie-charts/update-donut/
But I keep getting Typeerror failed to execute appendChild and the chart only show blue circle like image below.
my current npm package are
  "dependencies": {
    "apexcharts": "^4.0.0",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.10.2",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.28.0"
  },

What am I do wrong here?

const DonutChart = () => {
  const chartData = {

    series: [44, 55, 13, 33],
    options: {
      chart: {
        width: 380,
        type: 'donut',
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        options: {
          chart: {
            width: 200
          },
          legend: {
            show: false
          }
        }
      }],
      legend: {
        position: 'right',
        offsetY: 0,
        height: 230,
      }
    },
  }

  return (
    <>
      <ReactApexChart
        options={chartData.options}
        series={chartData.series}
        type="donut"
        width={300}
      />
    </>
  )
}


This was a bug in v4.0.0 of ApexCharts.
Please upgrade to apexcharts@4.1.0 which should fix this.
